# how do i use catalina.home in servlet?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea, properties, javabeans

`<beans proflie="myProfile">
     <context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.home}/webapps/dir/properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
</beans>` catalina.home not working but full path is working perfectly.

in my server there is tomcat 9 and when i start it, print CATALINA_HOME=var/user/share/tomcat9

Comment: Tomcat sets the `catalina.home` system property on JVM launch, so you should be able to use that. Can `<beans>` files use system properties in them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code `String homedir = System.getProperty("catalina.home");` to get the home directory of tomcat anywhere - servlet , jsp or java code.